# How can I refresh an SKScene embed in a previous View Controller when dismissing View Controller with ARSKView?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, arkit, skscene

In my SpriteKit game, I have two View Controllers. One is my MenuViewController, which has an SKView/SKScene in it - this handles the level selection, etc.

I then have my GameSceneViewController - this has an ARSKView/SKScene in it. When a user completes multiple levels and, for example, earns 3 stars for each one, and then uses the pause menu to go back to the MenuViewController, the stars that show for each level are (obviously) not refreshed.

This is because at the moment, when a user wants to go back to the MenuViewController, I simply call:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I was wondering if there is a function I could call to "refresh" the MenuSceneController when a user dismisses the GameSceneViewController.

Answer (score 0):

First of all add the following method to `MenuSceneController`

```
class MenuSceneController: UIViewController {

    func reloadScene() {
        // write here your logic to reload the scene
    }
}
```

Now when you dismiss `GameSceneViewController` you can call that method

```
class GameSceneViewController: UIViewController {

    func goBackToMenu() {

        guard let menuSceneController = presentingViewController as? MenuSceneController else {
            debugPrint("Error, this view controller was not presented by a MenuSceneController")
            return
        }
        self.dismiss(animated: true) {
            menuSceneController.reloadScene()
        }
    }
}
```